# handle two different erro codes by exception handler in python

Tags: python, exception

HI  i am new python  and please excuse me if this seems to be a silly question .
I have a function in my code which returns an exception ResponseError 
and the ResponseError has two error codes 404 and 403 
I want my exception handler to give two different messages based on the error code 
if the error code is 404 it should say "file not exist "
if the error code  is 403 then "forbidden to access".

Comment: Please, share some code. Also, I assume you are using a framework?

Comment: Python Documentation is a good place looking at generic nature of question https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using urllib2 package in python then you could handle like this:

```
import urllib2
try:
   urllib2.urlopen("any url")
except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
   if err.code == 404:
       print "Files does not exit"
   elif err.code == 403:
       print "Forbidden to Access"
```

For example the below code will print out "files does not exist"

```
import urllib2
try:
   urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/events")
except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
   if err.code == 404:
       print "Files does not exit"
   elif err.code == 403:
       print "Forbidden to Access"

 output - `Files does not exist` since the above url does not exist.
```